# Set dynamic headers in Ionic 2 with angular2-jwt

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-jwt

When users login to my app they have to say to which club they belong. Once they select the club I save that in storage and attach it to header. Here is the code I currently have:

```
let storage: Storage = new Storage();

export function getSubdomain(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    storage.get('club').then(club => {
      console.log(club);

      resolve(club)
    })
  });
}

export function getAuthHttp(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    noJwtError: true,
    globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {'x-academy': getSubdomain()}],
    tokenGetter: (() => storage.get('id_token'))
 }), http, options);
}
```

Problem is that `getSubdomain()` function doesn't return the name before header is called. I understand that problem is async. It works perfectly fine if I put return "clubname". How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wansn't able to work the problem out using `Storage` so I had to use `localstorage.getItem('club')` since it's sync function and it looked like this:

```
export function getAuthHttp(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return getSubDomain().then(subDomain => 
    new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    noJwtError: true,
    globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {'x-academy': localstorage.getItem('club')}],
    tokenGetter: (() => storage.get('id_token'))
  }), http, options));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, `getSubDomain()` could be simplified as you can directly return the `storage.get('club')` result.

As you mentioned your problem is an async one, you can solve it by waiting for the promise to end before creating the other one, like this:

```
export function getAuthHttp(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return getSubDomain().then(subDomain => 
        new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        noJwtError: true,
        globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {'x-academy': subDomain}],
        tokenGetter: (() => storage.get('id_token'))
     }), http, options));
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It sends me back this.authHttp.post is not a function. Do I need to make any changes in getSubDomain()?

Comment: This error seems to be from somewhere else because there's no post in the function i gave you

Comment: if hardcode in my header { 'x-academy': 'somestring' } my authHttp.post request works fine. I think that getAuthHttp function should return new AuthHttp and the way you suggested I don't think it does.

Comment: It can't return new authhttp immediatly so it has to be a promise because you get club from a promise.

Comment: Any suggestion how to do that? :)

Comment: With a promise there's no way, the only way would be to get club from localstorage in a synchronous way.

Comment: This wouldn't be ideal... I might have to add header to each request